# How to add currency to digital wallet through Uber APIs?

Tags: uber-api

I've a question related to Uber API's payment methods.

In India, Uber API allows 3 types of payments:
1. credit card
2. Paytm
3. cash

For payment method 2 - Paytm - I would like to know how to programmatically through Uber APIs add currency to the digital wallet? The Uber app allows adding of currency in the digital wallet - paytm.

I went through the Uber API documentation and it wasn't clear that this functionality could be done through the API.

So, I'm wondering whether the same functionality is possible through Uber APIs and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to add any digital currency through the Uber API.